# Ways to fullfil NaN Values for Intrusion Detection with ML, Unsupervised ML

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, intrusion-detection, network-flow

I created a CSV file. It contains 250800 rows and 75 columns. I am doing an EDA analysis to use the data for ML.
[image]

It looks like this. All of the columns are float or integer values. (df.info())
When I do :

```
df.dropna()
```

It removes NaN values but the issue is that columns like **protocol** lose all unique values and just have one value, same for **dstport** and this is not something I want, losing data is not welcoming. As suggested here, I did this:

```
df = df.dropna(subset = ["Protocol","DstPort", "State"])
```

But the result is the same, still same NaN values, and cannot apply Kmeans clustering for example.

I would like to ask for your suggestion. What should I do? Can I fill these values somehow, but I don't know in which sense?
Which machine learning model I should choose?

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 common ways to fill NaN values.

- Average: `df.fillna((df.mean()), inplace=True)`
- Most Frequent: `df[‘col’].fillna(df[‘col’].mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)`
- Median: `df.fillna((df.median()), inplace=True)`

I am not sure if this is the correct approach for my data since it is network traffic but just wanted to share.